# Ant file path question

Tags: ant

I have an Ant file that has this as a path. TRying to find out what it might mean.

deploy.dir = ${basedir}/..

First there is nowhere I can find where ${basedir} is being set. Is this some variable type being set in another file on the server or does ${basedir} mean the same directory the build file is in?

Then what does /.. mean after it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html will explain that ${basedir} is, by default, where you are sitting when you type 'ant'.

.. means what it means on Windows and Linux in pathnames: one directory up.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of ${basedir} is the directory containing your build xml file. This is even true if you say basedir="." in the project element. However, if on the command line, you say:

-Dbasedir=.

then it will be where you are sitting when executing ant. Since in most cases the build xml file will be where you are sitting, the difference shouldn't matter.